# Texto por cima de div com bordas

Tags: html, css

Fala galera! Tenho uma div .apresentacao, nela apliquei bordas para se tornar um triangulo. Beleza, más quero colocar um texto acima, porém com as bordas modificadas da .apresentacao, não fica alinhado.
Como posso melhorar esse meu codigo?
Obrigado pessoal! :)

CODE:

```css
.apresentacao {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid #f0ad4e;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #f0ad4e;
}
```

```html
<div class="apresentacao">
  <div class="texto">
    Aqui vem um texto qualquer
    <br/>texotexto.
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja se é isso:

```css
.apresentacao {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid #f0ad4e;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #f0ad4e;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.texto {
  width: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="apresentacao">
    <div class="texto">
      Aqui vem um texto qualquer
      texto
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Posição absoluta e relativa +1

Comment: Rapaz, eu tinha colocado absolute e relative antes más não tava funcionando. Que coisa estranha. OBRIGADO pela resposta. vou ver o que aconteceu!! :)